# Populating dbmanager Data into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

im new to iOS development.
This is small Restaurant type app. depending on restaurant it will populate the promotions.
i have done all that so far and getting list of promotion to array in viewdidLoad method.

```
if (!dbmanager)dbmanager = [[DBManager alloc]init];
    array = [dbmanager getPromotions:[NSNumber numberWithInt:restId]];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count);
```

and using this i can get the details of Promotion Details into Log

```
for (PromotionTbl *order in array) {
        NSLog(@"%@",order.promoName);
    }
```

i want to populate these data in tableview so i have done the normal implemantation for tableview and

add cell like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"promoName"];
```

but im getting error saying

`2015-11-16 11:20:35.825 Eatin[2858:1201859] -[PromotionTbl objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb507b3ab0
2015-11-16 11:20:35.834 Eatin[2858:1201859] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PromotionTbl objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb507b3ab0'`

I have done without `objectForKey` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying data into cell, do like this :

```
PromotionTbl *order = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = order.promoName;
cell.imageView.image = order.promotionImage; // If you want to display as a logo or thumbnail

// If you have image URL and download image from it and then display
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:order.promotionImageURL]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    if (data)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }
}];
```

If you want to display large image then, add `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to cell and assign data to it. Or you can create custom cell having `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.

Comment: and can you tell me how can i assign image to that cell? in tableView there is Image as `order.promotionImage`

Answer (score 1):

if you really sure that your array contain PromotionTbl, you can cast the object in array to PromotionTbl and access its value.

```
PromotionTbl *order = (PromotionTbl*)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = order.promoName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get object of PromotionTbl and then you can access the properties of the model.

```
PromotionTbl promotionModel = (PromotionTbl*)array[indexPath.row];

if(promotionModel != nil) {
    cell.textLabel.text = order.promoName;
}
```